# Generating random numbers under very specific constraints

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I am faced with the following programming problem. I need to generate `n` `(a, b)` tuples for which the sum of all `a`'s is a given `A` and sum of all `b`'s is a given `B` and for each tuple the ratio of `a / b` is in the range `(c_min, c_max)`. `A / B` is within the same range, too. I am also trying to make sure there is no bias in the result other than what is introduced by the constraints and the `a / b` values are more-or-less uniformly distributed in the given range.

Some clarifications and meta-constraints:

- `A`, `B`, `c_min`, and `c_max` are given.
- The ratio `A / B` is in the `(c_min, c_max)` range. This has to be so if the problem is to have a solution given the other constraints.
- a and b are `>0` and non-integer.

I am trying to implement this in Python but ideas in any language (English included) are much appreciated.

Comment: Are `a` and `b` integers within a certain range?

Comment: What guarantees can you make about `A/B`?

Comment: @Mark: No they aren't. @dmckee: `A/B` is in the same range `(c_min, c_max)`.

Comment: If the sums have to be given constants, the generated tuples can't be random. They can (maybe) be random if either A or B (but not both) is a constant if you work backwards from generating numbers in (c_min, c_max).

Comment: each of your requirements contradicts the notion of randomness. I think this premise needs to be re-considered.

Comment: I assume a, b, A, B, and c_min, c_max are all positive integers? (you didn't say so I want to be absolutely sure). And what are the _given_ values? I assume n, A, B, c_min, and c_max are given and you have to go find n tuples (a, b). But your comment about A/B needing to be in the range implies that A and B are somehow variable (although you said they're constant). Just seeking clarification.

Comment: @Inerdia: You are right. Call them pseudorandom. We are, after all, picking a certain n-tuple out of a solution set that, theoretically at least, has multiple members.

Comment: Also, this probably belongs on math.stackexchange.com more than here.

Comment: @kaloyan OK, define "pseudorandom". What *specific* deviations from "randomness" are acceptable to satisfy the constraints?

Comment: @Inerdia: As long as the constraints are satisfied and the result is non-trivial (any `a = A / n`, `b = B / n`), the result is satisfactory. To make it a *good* solution, I would like to get the variance of the `a`s, `b`s and `(a / b)`s as close to the variance of the uniform distribution as possible. How close this is, I don't know for sure.

Comment: **uniformly distributed random** is an oxymoron ... the fact that it is *random* means it isn't uniformly anything.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Please refer to an introductory statistics textbook – the distribution of random variables is a core concept of the field. In fact, a uniform distribution is the "most random" (in the intuitive sense) of the distributions.

Comment: I think the problem here (with all of these terrible solutions below) is that it is very difficult to reason about the distribution of probabilities that are conditional on an event with probability zero.  If you generate tuples uniformly then the probability that they will satisfy your constraints is zero, so when you try compute the distribution you are "dividing zero by zero" in a sense and you can easily get different answers.  This is also known as the Borel-Kolmogorov paradox (look it up on Wikipedia).  In other words, you have to define a measure before a distribution can be "unbaised".

Comment: @kaloyan: Practically any distribution can be tuned to match the variance of the uniform distribution.  This is probably not what you want.

Comment: @Inerdia if you can guarantee the output is uniformly distributed it isn't random. I can flip a coin 1 million times, if I guarantee that 500,000 of the results are always heads and 500,000 are always tails by definition it isn't random. Statistics try and explain what the predicted output might be expected to look like, not what it will be.

Comment: This more of a [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/) question than a programming question.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: "uniform" means the *probability* of a given coin flip being heads is 50%, and the *probability* of it being tails is 50%. The uniformity isn't a guarantee – whether *any single* coin toss will be heads or tails is still random. However, the coin toss being uniformly distributed also means that it is *very likely* that in a million tries the total number of heads will be *very close* to 500,000. (Because the sum of a million uniformly distributed random variables is *not* uniformly distributed.)

Comment: How large is `n` ? If `n` is moderate, you can try rejection. Don't worry about the equality constraints, it is easy to sample uniformly under such constraints (and easy to get it wrong). The range constraint is more of a concern here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by generating as many identical tuples, n, as you need:

`(A/n, B/n)`

Now pick two tuples at random.  Make a random change to the `a` value of one, and a compensating change to the `a` value of the other, keeping everything within the given constraints.  Put the two tuples back.

Now pick another random pair.  This times twiddle with the `b` values.

Lather, rinse repeat.

Comment: When should you stop the procedure and how do you enforce that `a/b` are more-or-less uniformly distributed?

Comment: Stopping is a difficult question.  I suggest running enough to make sure that each tuple has both `a` and `b` twiddled.  Perhaps work systematically through the list for the first of each pair of tuples.  After a complete pass do a statistical check.  If it fails then do another complete pass.

Comment: @rossum: What kind of "statistical check"?  It is generally impossible to look at a random sample and say, "Yes, that's uniform."

Comment: @Dietrich Epp Ask the OP.  The request is for "no bias" and "more or less uniform".  I am presuming that the OP has some way to test that those criteria are satisfied.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: of course it is possible. You take samples, you evaluate they're (discrete) distribution function and you check whether this function equals a given distribution up to a given error.

Comment: I'm talking about evaluating a *single sample* (e.g., one set of tuples) for matching a distribution.  It becomes more obvious that it is impossible if you simplify the problem.  For example, if you have an algorithm for generating numbers between 1 and 6, and it generates a 4, how do you know if it is generating the numbers uniformly, and how do you know if you should go back and regenerate the number?  The only way to answer the question is to understand how the number was generated in the first place.

Comment: It is in fact, maximally useless to try and do a statistical test against a model with a uniform distribution, since the likelihood function is constant.  You will never get any information.

Comment: Well, in this situation you use empirical solution. You generate data and you hold it in a list. Then you check whether the distribution is more or less uniform. When you generate another number you do the test again. If it is still ok then you may assume that the next sample match the distribution. Obviously you cannot tell anything about distribution if you have only one sample! :) But this is not the case!

Comment: This doesn't work for `c_min = c_max = 1`, `A = B = 2n`.  The correct solution has answers like a = b = [2, 2,...], and a = b = [1,3,...], but the transition from the first to second is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

We look for tuples a_i and b_i such that

- (a_1, ... a_n) and (b_1, ... b_n) have a distribution which is invariant under permutation of indices (what you would call "unbiased")
- the ratios a_i / b_i are uniformly distributed on [cmin, cmax]
- sum(a_i) = A, sum(b_i) = B

If `c_min` and `c_max` are not too ill conditioned (ie they are not very close to another), and `n` is not very large, the following works:

- Generate `a_i` "uniformly" such that `sum a_i = A`:

  - Draw `n` samples `aa_i` (`i = 1..n`) from some distribution (eg. uniform)
  - Divide them by their sum and multiply by A: `a_i = A * aa_i / sum(aa_i)` has desired properties.
- Generate `b_i` such that `sum b_i = B` by the same method.
- If there exists `i` such that `a_i / b_i` is not in the interval `[cmin, cmax]`, throw away *all* the `a_i` and `b_i` and try again from the beginning.

It **doesn't** scale well with `n`, because the set of `a_i` and `b_i` satisfying the constraints gets more and more narrow as `n` increases (and so you reject more candidates).

To be honest, I don't see any other simple solution. If `n` gets large and `cmin ~ cmax`, then you will have to use a sledgehammer (eg. MCMC) to generate samples from your distribution, unless there is some trick we did not see.

---

If you really want to use MCMC algorithms, note that you can change `cmin` to `cmin * B / A` (likewise for `cmax`) and assume `A == B == 1`. The problem is then to draw uniformly on the product of two unit n-simplices (u_1...u_n, v_1...v_n) such that

```
u_i / v_i \in [cmin, cmax].
```

So you have to use a MCMC algorithm (Metropolis-Hastings seems more suited) on the product of two unit n-simplices with the density

```
f(u_1, ..., u_n, v_1, ..., v_n) = \prod indicator_{u_i/v_i \in [cmin, cmax]}
```

which is definitely doable (albeit involved).

Comment: And there's the difference between mathematicians and programmers. :) See my answer. The solution that does not involve generating numbers over and over. Not to mention some really unnecessary things like MCMC.

Comment: @freakish: Your answer does not give uniformly distributed a_i nor b_i. It doesn't even yield independent a_i. I claim you can get 1/ independent uniform a_i 2/ independent uniform b_i which satisfy the constraints.

Comment: @Alexander C.: sorry, mate, but it is impossible to make `a_i` independent. You can claim whatever you want, but math does not lie! :) Sum of all `a_i` is `A` so how can they be independent? And there are more subtle conditions on both `a_i` and `b_i`. See my theoretical explanation in my answer.

Comment: @freakish: independent = "projectively" independent, ie. the distribution of the a_i should at least be invariant by permutation of the indices. I claim that you can take for a_i independent variables divided by A.

Comment: @Alexander C.: `a_i/A` are still dependent, since they're sum is `1`. :) Moreover these variables have to satisfy system of linear equations which I wrote in my theoretical explanation. Believe me, I'm a mathematician and I know what I'm saying. :) But if you are sure that I am wrong, then please post your solution with mathematical explanation that it is correct. :)

Comment: @freakish: sorry, by "divided by A" I meant "divided by their sum".

Comment: @Alexander C.: This becomes really complicated. Post your (full) answer and I will gladly admit that I'm wrong.

Comment: @freakish: Forget my cluttered explanation. A simple point I can make against your solution is that the a_i (and the b_i) have a distribution which is not invariant by permutation of indices. This is certainly a desirable feature to have here.

Comment: @Alexander C.: I have implemented your method. Please see this: http://rafael-x.blogspot.com/2011/10/stackoverflow-discussion.html for the code and the comment. As you can see it works very bad even for `n=50` and the parameters are the same like in my solution. Except that my works almost instantly even for `n=10000`. :) What is the relation between generating `aa_i` and `c_min`, `c_max`? Because this seems to be the main problem. By the way: the link is my personal blog (in Polish) and I will delete this post in few days.

Comment: @freakish: n=50 is already big. The time needed for rejection scales exponentially with n.

Comment: @Alexander C.: So let us do some compromise. Your solution is simple and correct, but the time for the algorithm to stop (if it stops) is unacceptable. On the other hand my solution requires some higher algebra knowledge and it is also correct with the exception that two samples may interfere with the requirement for samples to be uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest thing is to

1. Use your favorite method to throw `n-1` values such that `\sum_i=0,n-1 a_i < A`, and set a_n to get the right total. There are several SO question about doing that, though I've never seen a answer I'm really happy with yet. Maybe I'll write a paper or something.
2. Get the `n-1` `b`'s by throwing the `c_i` uniformly on the allowed range, and set final `b` to get the right total and check on the final c (I think it must be OK, but I haven't proven it yet).

Note that since we have 2 hard constrains we should expect to throw `2n-2` random numbers, and this method does exactly that (on the assumption that you can do step 1 with `n-1` throws.

Comment: Point 1 gives a biased distribution for the a_i. Better is to draw directly n values and 1/ divide them by their sum 2/ multiply by A.

Comment: The answer is incorrect. There is no guarantee that the last quotient `a_n/b_n` is in a given range. This is not so trivial. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Blocked Gibbs sampling is pretty simple and converges to the right distribution (this is along the lines of what Alexandre is proposing).

1. For all i, initialize a<sub>i</sub> = A / n and b<sub>i</sub> = B / n.
2. Select i ≠ j uniformly at random. With probability 1/2, update a<sub>i</sub> and a<sub>j</sub> with uniform random values satisfying the constraints. The rest of the time, do the same for b<sub>i</sub> and b<sub>j</sub>.
3. Repeat Step 2 as many times as seems to be necessary for your application. I have no idea what the convergence rate is.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good ideas here. Thanks! **Rossum**'s idea seemed the most straightforward implementation-wise so I went for it. Here is the code for posterity:

```
c_min = 0.25
c_max = 0.75
a_sum = 100.0
b_sum = 200.0
n = 1000 

a = [a_sum / n] * n
b = [b_sum / n] * n

while not good_enough(a, b):
    i, j = random.sample(range(n), 2)
    li, ui = c_min * b[i] - a[i], c_max * b[i] - a[i]
    lj, uj = a[j] - c_min * b[j], a[j] - c_max * b[j]
    llim = max((li, uj))
    ulim = min((ui, lj))
    q = random.uniform(llim, ulim)
    a[i] += q
    a[j] -= q

    i, j = random.sample(range(n), 2)
    li, ui = a[i] / c_max - b[i], a[i] / c_min - b[i]
    lj, uj = b[j] - a[j] / c_max, b[j] - a[j] / c_min
    llim = max((li, uj))
    ulim = min((ui, lj))
    q = random.uniform(llim, ulim)
    b[i] += q
    b[j] -= q
```

The `good_enough(a, b)` function can be a lot of things. I tried:

- Standard deviation, which is hit or miss, as you don't know what is a good enough value.
- Kurtosis, where a large negative value would be nice. However, it is relatively slow to calculate and is undefined with the seed values of `(a_sum / n, b_sum / n)` (though that's trivial to fix).
- Skewness, where a value close to `0` is desirable. But it has the same drawbacks as kurtosis.
- A number of iterations proportional to `n`. `2n` sometimes wasn't enough, `n ^ 2` is a little bit of overkill and is, well, exponential.

Ideally, a heuristic using a combination of skewness and kurtosis would be best but I settled for making sure each value has been changed from the initial (again, as **rossum** suggested in a comment). Though there is no theoretical guarantee that the loop will complete, it seemed to work well enough for me.

Comment: Can anyone classify the algorithm? Looks MCMC-ish to me but I don't know enough about it to be able to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I think from mathematical point of view. We have sequences `a_i` and `b_i` such that sum of `a_i` is `A` and sum of `b_i` is `B`. Furthermore `A/B` is in `(x,y)` and so is `a_i/b_i` for each `i`. Furthermore you want `a_i/b_i` to be uniformly distributed in `(x,y)`.

So do it starting from the end. Choose `c_i` from `(x,y)` such that they are uniformly distributed. Then we want to have the following equality `a_i/b_i = c_i`, so `a_i = b_i*c_i`.

Therefore we only need to find `b_i`. But we have the following system of linear equations:

```
A = (sum)b_i*c_i
B = (sum)b_i
```

where `b_i` are variables. Solve it (some fancy linear algebra tricks) and you're done!

Note that for large enough `n` this system will have lots of solutions. They will be dependent on some parameters which you can choose randomly.

---

Enough of the theoretical approach, let's see some practical solution.

// EDIT 1: Here's some hard core Python code :D

```
import random
min = 0.0
max = 10.0
A = 500.0
B = 100.0

def generate(n):
    C = [min + i*(max-min)/(n+1) for i in range(1, n+1)]
    Y = [0]
    for i in range(1,n-1):
        # This line should be changed in order to always get positive numbers
        # It should be relatively easy to figure out some good random generator
        Y.append(random.random())
    val = A - C[0]*B
    for i in range(1, n-1):
        val -= Y[i] * (C[i] - C[0])
    val /= (C[n-1] - C[0])
    Y.append(val)
    val = B
    for i in range(1, n):
        val -= Y[i]
    Y[0] = val
    result = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        result.append([ Y[i]*C[i], Y[i] ])
    return result
```

The result is a list of pairs `(X,Y)` satisfying your conditions with the exception that they may be negative (see the random generator line in code) i.e. the first and the last pair may contain negative numbers.

// EDIT 2:

Too ensure that they are positive you may try something like

```
Y.append(random.random() * B / n)
```

instead of

```
Y.append(random.random())
```

I'm not sure though.

// EDIT 3:

In order to have better results try something like this:

```
avrg = B / n
ran = avrg / 20
for i in range(1, n-1):
    Y.append(random.gauss(avrg, ran))
```

instead of

```
for i in range(1, n-1):
    Y.append(random.random())
```

This will make all `b_i` to be near `B / n`. Unfortunetly the last term will still sometimes jump high. I'm sorry, but there is no way to avoid this (mathematics) since the last and the first terms depend on the others. For small `n` (~100) it looks good though. Unfortunetly some negative values may appear.

The choice of a correct generator is not so simple if you additionally want `b_i` to be uniformly distributed.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write some code :). And, yes, your solution does satisfy the conditions but, sadly, results in really biased numbers: a lot of small tuples and then one or two big ones. If you plot them in `(a, b)` space you will see that most number pairs are bunched around the origin and the first and last ones are way out there with much larger values.

Comment: Well, it all depends on this line: `Y.append(random.random())`. You may try some different generators. Perhaps `random.gauss()`? Also note that it might be impossible to get all pairs `(a,b)` to be (more or less) evenly distributed. But I'll think about it. :) After all `a` depends on `b` and there are other strong limitations on them.

Comment: *(deleted old lengthy comment)* Stated more clearly: your solution gives a_i and b_i whose distribution is not invariant by permutation of indices (although a_i/b_i is). This is certainly not desirable.